# How do i limit a value taken from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a table which has values i want to retrieved in json format and put in android. My question is how do i limit 1 value to only 1?

Here is my code

```
$sql = "SELECT * from news  Order by n_date Desc";
 $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 


 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


 $response = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
array_push($response, array("NID"=>$row['NID'], "title"=>$row[2], "content"=>$row[3], "n_date"=>(new DateTime($row[4]))->format('M d, Y l g:i:s A')));
 }



echo json_encode (array("news_response"=>$response));




mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Example is for n_date i only want to display the date 1 time. But it keeps on looping. How do i limit the date to only 1 where everything else loops?

Example is like this

```
      {"news_response":[{"NID":"2","title":"2016","
    content":"Hello World ",
    "n_date":"Feb 17, 2017 Friday 11:01:57 PM"},{"NID":"1","title":"Hello there",
"content":"Hello there hehe"}]}
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY n_date DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: it limits everything into 1, i need only 1 value to be limited to 1 and others are not limited to 1

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  You want to limit a "date" and yet the example has no date in it.  You should provide clear sample data and desired results.

Comment: added an example of data sir

Comment: *"My question is how do i limit 1 value to only 1?"* - you answered your own question *lol* - `limit 1` ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- i dont how to say it haha. I provided a sample result above

Comment: well someone popped an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the data, you can change your SQL query by adding a LIMIT:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY n_date DESC LIMIT 1";
```

If you need more information, you can look into the MySQL Reference Manual:

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: it limits everything to 1 sir, I only need to limit n_date to 1 not everything